# JSON.stringify object containing unicode/utf8/line feed

Tags: javascript, php, json, unicode

I am trying to come to grips with the issues involved with exchanging data containing newlines and unicode chars between PHP and Javascript.  My tests, in Chrome, suggest only one real problem - JavaScript cannot JSON.parse anything containing new line chars (and other control chars too I imagine?)

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8JdaJ/) that demonstrates some of my experiments.  Here is how the PHP JSON output was generated

```
<?php
$x = '{"hwWithLF":"Hello World!\nHow are you","hwInChinese":
"世界，你  好","index":2,"good":false}';

header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');
$x = json_decode($x);
echo json_encode($x);
?>
```

I am in the final stages of testing out my application prior to release and have only limited knowledge of the issues that might arise owing to such features in the JSON interchanges between server and client.

I'd be much obliged to anyone who might be able to suggest the *dos*, *dont's* and *gotchas* involved here. Quite apart from the subtleties of coding such exchanges right are there any browser-specific issues that one should be aware of?

Comment: For Json Text:                                                      The MIME media type for JSON text is application/json. The default encoding is UTF-8. (Source: [link](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt) ).                           Instead of content type as text/plain below is recommended one       - `code`header('Content-type: text/json');

Comment: @caspersky Actually, the correct MIME type for JSON is `application/json` as per [RFC 4627](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4627).

Comment: I started sending out the text/plain header a long time ago when I found that jQuery had an unfortunate habit of wanting to try and parse the JSON for me - something I specifically did not want to happen. Perhaps that is not an issue anymore, or there are other ways to stop it, but it is in my code base now and would take too much effort to change.

Answer (score 0):

> My tests, in Chrome, suggest only one real problem - JavaScript cannot `JSON.parse` anything containing new line chars (and other control chars too I imagine?)

`JSON.parse` does handle new lines correctly. I don’t see any mistakes problems with the fiddle you linked too, either.

```
> JSON.stringify('foo\nbar')
'"foo\\nbar"'
> JSON.parse('"foo\\nbar"')
'foo\nbar'
```

One thing to keep in mind though is that raw U+2028 and U+2029 characters can be part of a JSON-formatted string, but they cannot occur in a JavaScript string literal since JavaScript treats them as line terminator characters (i.e. newlines). See [***Hacking with Unicode, slides 134–146***](https://speakerdeck.com/mathiasbynens/hacking-with-unicode?slide=134).

Comment: I had a consistent problem with \n characters being passed from JS to PHP.  There is a simple test for this which I will fiddle up when I have a minute.  The "solution" I found was to [*addslashes*](http://phpjs.org/functions/addslashes/)  the JSON.stringify output and then call stripslashes on that value in PHP prior to attempting anything else.

Comment: there are never any issues with the pure JS to JS example you have shown.  The thing I want to ensure I have dealt with 100% is issues arising from JS to PHP/PHP to JS JSON transfers.

Comment: Keep in mind that PHP handles escape sequences differently depending on whether a string literal uses single-quotes or double-quotes. `\n` is not an escape sequence in a single-quoted string literal, only in a double-quoted string literal. See the documentation: [PHP Strings](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php)

Comment: @DroidOS PHP’s `json_encode` works correctly, if that’s what you’re asking. Your confusion might be based on PHP’s behavior with single-quoted vs. double-quoted strings, as @Remy mentioned.